# Master/Detail records query

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to find a better way to show employee detail when the user clicks on the user name.

My question is: Do I need to add another SOQL query or I can use what I have?, so when the user clicks on the employee name, I want to show detail like Salary, Address, etc...

I need help in building SOQL query.

my APEX code:

```
 String myId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id'); 
 employeeSQL = [SELECT id,name,RecordType.Name FROM Employee__c WHERE Id = :myId];

  for(Employee__c e : employeeSQL ){
        empList.add(e);
  }
```

Data Data

```
Employee_Detail__c: {
    Id=a0Ao000000c8nbMEAQ,
    Name=John Smith, 
    salary=120
    Address__c=123 main st ca 90717,    
    CurrencyIsoCode=USD
},
Employee_Detail__c: {
    Id=a0Ao000000c8nbNEAB,
    Name=John Erich, 
    salary=80
    Address__c=123 main st ca 90717,    
    CurrencyIsoCode=USD
})
```

[image]

Comment: A common approach to modelling people (including employees) is to add any necessary custom fields (and record types) to Contact so there is only a single object rather than a completely custom object or some fields in a one object and some fields in another object. One SObject for one domain object keeps code simple.

Answer (score 7):

You can add the data to an existing query as a sub-query, basically like so:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Name, Salary__c, Address__c FROM Employee_Details__r) FROM Employee__c ...
```

In Visualforce, you can iterate over those details using the apex:repeat, apex:dataTable, or apex:pageBlockTable elements as you desire. You'll need to add a bit of Visualforce logic to actually show/hide the elements, but that should be pretty trivial.

Comment: i'm getting this error `Didn't understand relationship 'employee_Detail__r' in FROM part of query call`

Comment: Check the relationship field on employee detail object. It may be a different name.